# can anyone teach me how the Maximally Stable Extremal Region (MSER) formula works in detail?

Tags: computer-vision, mser

im so confused right now, because i still dont understand how to find maxVariation, minArea, maxArea, and thresholdDelta value in manual calculation in MSER. [specially on this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALRa5.png) can anyone tell me how to solve this formula? Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related

Comment: why..? mser is algoritm but i want to know how that work in manual calculation..

Comment: You’re asking about mathematics, not about programming. There is a Stack Exchange site specifically for mathematics: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: alright than..thank you very much..